# Calculus on the Sobolev space valued function of one real variable $t$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Now I am interested in the calculus on Banach space valued function, especially the function with value in a certain Sobolev space. I want to prove that $$\bigcap_{k=0}^m C^k([0,T];H^{m-k}(\Omega))\subset C^{m-[\frac{n}{2}]-1}(\overline{Q_T}),\tag{1}$$by Sobolev imbedding  theorem. Here $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Q_T:=(0,T)\times\Omega$. Since I'm not familiar with the theory of Banach space valued function (only know some basic concepts), I wish to see the detail proof of $(1)$. Any reference which contain the detail proof of $(1)$ is exceedingly welcome!

Any answer and reference will be appreciated!

Comment: The space in the left hand side can be shown to be in $H^{m}(Q_T)$, but the exponent $k=m-[\frac{n}2]-1$ is equal to $m-\frac{n+1}2$ when $n$ is odd, which means that we cannot prove the assertion by the (false) embedding $H^{m}(Q_T)\subset C^k(Q_T)$. So if the assertion is true, one must use a direct approach. What is the reason you believe that the assertion is true?

Answer (score 1):

Sweeping out the trash, reformulate what indeed is needed to be established:
$$
\bigcap_{k=0}^{m-[\frac{n}{2}]-1}C^k\bigl([0,T];H^{m-k}(\Omega)\bigr)\subset 
C^{m-[\frac{n}{2}]-1}\Bigl(\overline{Q}_T\Bigr),
$$
which in fact immediately follows by an *a priori* inclusion
$$
\bigcap_{k=0}^{l}C^k\bigl([0,T];C^{l-k}(\overline{\Omega})\bigr)\subset 
C^{l}\Bigl(\overline{Q}_T\Bigr)$$
due to the embedding $\,H^{j}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow C^{j-[\frac{n}{2}]-1}
\bigl(\overline{\Omega}\bigr)\,$ valid for all integer $j\geqslant [\frac{n}{2}]+1$.